# Synchronously call a AJAX Function from Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I tried a few times to reload a certain content of my webpage via an AJAX call from a Javascript timer function, but it still doesn't work.
I know that normally its not that easy to make it work.

Does anybody have an idea how this could work.
I already found some solutions here but they are not working for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, AJAX request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re)

Comment: You need to include the code you're trying to use and we can help you with what is wrong with that code.  Also why do you need synchronous as opposed to the usual asynchronous Ajax operation?